# Optimizing for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, optimization

I have a dataframe (df) with distance traveled and I have assigned a label based on certain conditions.

```
distance=[0,0.0001,0.20,1.23,4.0]
df = pd.DataFrame(distance,columns=["distance"])
df['label']=0
for i in range(0, len(df['distance'])):   
      if (df['distance'].values[i])<=0.10:
          df['label'][i]=1
      elif (df['distance'].values[i])<=0.50:
          df['label'][i]=2
      elif (df['distance'].values[i])>0.50:
          df['label'][i]=3
```

This is working fine. However, I have more than 1 million records with distance and this for loop is taking longer time than expected. Can we optimize this code to reduce the execution time?

Comment: i think you could shave off micro seconds if the last `elif...` became just an `else:`

Comment: presumably your second elif should b `0.10 < df['distance'].values[i])<=0.50`? I'd probably create a new dataframe column for each condition and then merge them, slicing then broadcasting should be quicker than looping

Comment: Two things: how das `df['label'][i] = 1` not create an error, if you set `df['label']` to `0`? And: don't know if you use python2 or python3 - but foor python2 replace `range` with `xrange`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't loop over DataFrames unless it's absolutely necessary. You'll usually get much better performance using a built-in Pandas function that's already been optimized, or by using a vectorized approach.

In this case, you can use `loc` and [Boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to do the assignments:

```
# Initialize as 1 (eliminate need to check the first condition).
df['label'] = 1

# Case 1: Between 0.1 and 0.5
df.loc[(df['distance'] > 0.1) & (df['distance'] <= 0.5), 'label'] = 2

# Case 2: Greater than 0.5
df.loc[df['distance'] > 0.5, 'label'] = 3
```

Another option is to use [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html).  This is a method is a little more specialized to the example problem in the question.  Boolean indexing is a more general method.

```
# Get the low and high bins.
low, high = df['distance'].min()-1, df['distance'].max()+1

# Perform the cut.  Add one since the labels start at zero by default.
df['label'] = pd.cut(df['distance'], bins=[low, 0.1, 0.5, high], labels=False) + 1
```

You could also use `labels=[1,2,3]` in the code above, and not add 1 to the result.  This would give `df['labels']` categorical dtype instead of integer dtype though.  Depending on your use case this may or may not be important.

The resulting output for either method:

```
   distance  label
0    0.0000      1
1    0.0001      1
2    0.2000      2
3    1.2300      3
4    4.0000      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) by assigning labels to the bins:

```
pd.cut(df.distance, [-np.inf, 0.1, 0.5, np.inf], labels=[1,2,3])

0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Comes with a warning about setting a value on a copy of a slice, but maybe someone can suggest a cleaner alternative?

Just based on fancy indexing to get the sub-array based on distance and then writing the values you want to it.

```
df.loc[:, "label"][df.loc[:, "distance"] <= 0.1] = 1
df.loc[:, "label"][(0.1 < df.loc[:, "distance"]) & (df.loc[:, "distance"] <= 0.5)] = 2
df.loc[:, "label"][df.loc[:, "distance"] > 0.5] = 3
```

EDIT: New and improved, without chained indexing.